# Stashing a file added with --intent-to-add

Tags: git, git-stash

I am using the `--intent-to-add` option with `git add` to easily add files using `git commit -a`. However, it seems like this confuses `git stash`. For example:

```
git init
touch a
git add a
git commit -m 1
touch b
git add --intent-to-add b
git stash --include-untracked
```

gives output from `git stash` :

```
error: Entry 'b' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
Cannot save the current worktree state
```

Why does this happen? Can it be fixed?

Answer (score 4):

Given a `git stash` followed by `git stash pop` will clear the index anyway, I would start with `git reset --keep` to clear the index. (With `--keep`, this won't change your local files or your commits, it only clears the index.)

```
git reset --keep
git stash --include-untracked
```

Once you've done the stuff you needed the stash for, you have to redo `git add --intent-to-add b` since you undid it with the reset:

```
git stash pop
git add --intent-to-add b
```

As for why this happens in the first place, I don't know. Seems like a bug to me... You can stash a regular `git add`, afterall.